# Colocalization analysis with Ripley’s K- and L-functions

Tags: python, r, image-processing, bioinformatics

I have about > 100 fluorescence images with 2 signals looking like this:

[image]

I wrote a program which extracts the **x and y position** of every red and blue signal and now I want to check if there is some kind of colocalization. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? I searched for lots of papers and programs but they use pixel intensity and not x/y-coordinates for calculation.

There is one interesting [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15095#Sec8) where they calculated L-function based on the distribution of T cells within a certain radius from cancer cells to calculate a colocalization. How do I use Ripley’s K function or L function for colocalization analysis?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same. Thanks for the paper. I'll report any results I can get.

Comment: @RicardoGuerreiro No problem... Have you already got any results? I am still struggeling with my problem :(

Comment: Hey, I found a very interesting python package with tutorial on neighbour distances and Ripley's K and L:  https://github.com/pysal/pointpats/blob/master/notebooks/distance_statistics-numpy-oriented.ipynb 

However, it doesn't do co-localization. I imagine you would need an altered function that only considers distances to neighbours of a different label, might need to adapt their code. I was also imagining to use local Moran's I, using the labels and a matrix of distances between points. But I'm not sure that is statistically correct.